# Bitbucket Pipelines.yml is having issues with FTP

Tags: debian, shell, git, ftp, sftp

I have some code that I was using, sourced from samueldebruyn/debian-git.

It's been working for months but all of a sudden is giving me an error of:

```
+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease [113 kB]
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.54.132 80]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease [36.8 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages [8178 kB]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
```

The code is as follows:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  branches:  # Pipelines that run automatically on a commit to a branch can also be triggered manually
    live:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push -u $FTP_USERNAME_LIVE -p $FTP_PASSWORD_LIVE $FTP_URL_LIVE
    dev:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp push -u $FTP_USERNAME -p $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_URL
```

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it could be a temporary issue with the remote host, not with your code.  Try again later?

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda i've been having this issue since Thursday last week though?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the 404 error is because Debian has just released a new stable version, bullseye, and the security repositories for it use a different path than for buster, the old stable release.  In your case, you've explicitly specified `stable`, and so you started using bullseye automatically as soon as it became stable.

If you want to continue to use bullseye, the proper entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable-security main
```

Otherwise, you should change from `stable` to `buster`, and you'll continue to use the old version.  You may also want to contact the maintainer of that image and ask them to update it appropriately.